# Addthis is Undefined when I use addthis, When I load page by Ajax

Tags: javascript, addthis

I'm try to show 'addthis sharing' buttons when make ajax call. at the first call  by ajax, buttons does not show, but when I reload whole page everything is OK, buttons is right place.

I searched a lots of fixes but no one works for me.
one of them is **addthis.toolbox(); or window.addthis** but when I use word addthis insde JavaScript tag, browser debugger writes error 'addthis is undefined'.

please give me smart advice what's happen and how can I fix it ?

Code (it's a partial view which load from ajax Call):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxx" async="async"></script>

<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>

<script>
 addthis.toolbox(); // addthis - is undefined
</script>
```

[image: error screen]

Comment: You need to show us some working sample code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to show us what you are doing. A text description is not helpful when there is no code to go with it.

Comment: I have already add code example. Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fixed this problem.

In my project I have 3 View level

1. _layout
2. View
3. _partialview

I had addthis Js reference and button's Div inside the _partialView.

But when I move Js reference to View and change Url(add - &async=1) it works fine and now 'addthis' - is defined (till here is undefined).

Hare is full example:

View:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-'yourPubId'&async=1"></script>
//Some Code
```

_partialView:

```
//Some Code 
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        addthis.init(); 
        addthis.layers.refresh(); 
      });
</script>
```

Good luck, everyone can use this perfect plugin 'addthis' when you load page by Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

The async version of the addthis_widget.js script you're using was intended to be used for the newer dashboard tools, as the call to addthis.toolbox() is undefined because AddThis hasn't fully loaded yet. If you remove async="async" from the script, it should work.

Alternatively, you could add the async attribute this way:

```html
<script src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxx&async=1" type="text/javascript">
```

Then before you call addthis.toolbox(), make sure you call addthis.init().

https://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/05/07/a-brief-history-of-using-addthis-dynamically/

-Matt

AddThis Support

Comment: I think your answer looks like very logical, bur it's doesn't working, the error is same. I tried your 2 ways to fix this problem, bur there is no way. if you haven't any suggestion I'll continue to make some test scenarios to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the addthis_sharing_toolbox div you were using, which is in fact from the dashboard. In order to load this dynamically, leave the original script as is (ignore my last suggestion) and then call addthis.layers.refresh(). http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1692927-using-dashboard-configuration-tools-dynamically

Comment: Matt I can not call addthis.layers.refresh(), because 'addthis' is undefined every time. do you have some advice how can I use addthis word ? I think it needs some reference or something like that.

Comment: Matt I added screen, please see it.