# Uncaught ReferenceError: addthis is not defined while clicking on the share button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, addthis

I am using [addthis](https://www.addthis.com) on my HTML website. What I am doing is, I am displaying all the rows on the page, and each row has a separate share button. When the user clicks on the share button then I have to show all the social icons.

I tried the below code but I am getting an error in the console after clicking on the share button.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addthis is not defined

**Script.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-'idhere'&async=1"></script>

    $(document).on('click', '.companyShareWrap > a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var company_id=$(this).data("id"); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        method:'post',
        dataType: "json", 
        data:{company_id:company_id,action:"sharePages"},  
        success: function(data){
        $('.sharebuttonAjax').html(''); //clear previous social and metatags

        $(".sharebuttonAjax"+company_id).append(data['socialbuttons']); 
         addthis.init(); 
         addthis.layers.refresh(); 
    
        }
    });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
if($_REQUEST['action']=='sharePages'){
$c_id=$_POST['company_id'];
$sql = "SELECT `company_img`, `company_name`, `company_desc` FROM `tbl_companyList` WHERE  company_id=:company_id";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam('company_id', $c_id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();


$getsharebuttons='<style>.sharebuttonAjax{position: absolute;bottom: 35px;
left: -48px;}.at-label{display:none}.at-resp-share-element{width:170px;}.at-share-btn-elements{display:flex;}.at-style-responsive .at-share-btn{padding:0 !important}</style><div class="addthis_inline_share_toolbox" data-url="https://www.test.com/demo/index.php" data-title="'.$result['company_name'].'" data-description="'.$result['company_desc'].'" data-media="'.$result['company_img'].'" style="clear: both;">
            <div id="atstbx" class="at-resp-share-element at-style-responsive addthis-smartlayers addthis-animated at4-show" aria-labelledby="at-73d0007c-6879-44b0-b2ea-3f01c82d7f53" role="region">
                <div class="at-share-btn-elements"></div>
            </div>
        </div>';


$metatags="";
$getResult=array('metatags' =>$metatags,'socialbuttons'=>$getsharebuttons);                 

// print_r($getResult);
// die();
echo json_encode($getResult);


}
```

I am getting the response but social icons are not displaying. What can I try next?

Comment: Where is the JavaScript code, exactly? What does the JS look like, exactly? Please [edit] your post and provide a [mre] of your JS (do we really need that AJAX and the jQuery to reproduce this issue?). Currently, you have a `<script>` tag which loads AddThis and then some JS code _outside_ of any `<script>` tag. `<script>` tags are not valid inside a script. The dev tools provide
a **Network** tab.
Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? Did you try `https` instead of `http`?

Comment: I am getting 200 responses. I am using Ajax because on page load I am displaying all my list along with share button and once the user clicks on the share button the using Ajax I am displaying the share button...  I have shared only share button Ajax code

Comment: My question wasn’t why _you_ use AJAX, my question was if we need all this AJAX code to reproduce the error message; it sounds like all the code we need is `addThis;` and nothing more. [Edit] the post to address the other clarification requests, too.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I don't know what clarification you need now.  I am not sharing the current page. I am sharing the single row which is on the page.

Comment: I assume you previously had a look, but just in case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684985/addthis-is-undefined-when-i-use-addthis-when-i-load-page-by-ajax

Comment: I found the solution. Let me add the answer

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this really related to PHP, or is this a pure JS problem?